# Does gravity slow time? Or does slow time create gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, time, time-dilation

Does gravity slow time? Or does slow time create gravity?

I've never heard someone say that slow time creates gravity but based on my calculations, I'm seeing that slow time creates gravity.

Comment: Gravity *is* spacetime curvature, mass-energy curves spacetime.

Comment: "based on my calculations"  - you need to show us your calculations if you expect people to comment on them.

Comment: What is slow time?

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the Einstein Field Equations: $G_{\mu\nu}=8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}$

The left hand side is geometry (curvature of spacetime, e.g. gravity), the right hand side is the matter distribution of mass-energy in spacetime. You may think of slowed time as being gravity (a certain curvature in spacetime).

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, the gravitational field effects includes that various measurements, ways in which spacetime changes, to vary, depending on the curvature of the spacetime.

Time slowing or going faster is one effect of gravity. There are many others. There is no way you can derive all the effects of gravity from time slowing. An example is Special Relativity (SR), where time slows (or goes faster depending on the observer's frame of reference) just from relative motion, and there is no gravity. Similarly in SR space contracts (again depending on the frame of reference).

The BIG difference between Special and General Relativity is that in one you ignore gravity and in the other you account for it. If no gravity you can calculate all using SR. We've been able to quantize special relativistic quantum mechanics into the so called Quantum Field Theory, but GR has proven stubbornly difficult to quantize (and a quantum field theory of it does not work).

If you have something that derives GR from time dilation try to publish it in a standard physics journal. Here is not the place for non-mainstream theories. Yours does not sound possible